MoEngage: Deep Link Navigation in Push Notifications Not Working When App is Killed
I am facing an issue where the deep link navigation from push notifications does not work when the app is killed, it works fine when the app is either active or in the background. MoEngage React Native SDK version I'm currently using is 9.1.0, I also have AppDelegate swizzling disabled for iOS.
From what I understand a deeplink should be obtained via Linking.getInitialURL(). While it partly works for Android (but the link can't be used as is), it doesn't work at all for iOS
The workaround I'm currently using is:
// MainActivity.kt
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val originalIntent = intent
    if (originalIntent.extras != null) {
        val remoteMessage = RemoteMessage(originalIntent.extras)
        if (MoEPushHelper.getInstance().isFromMoEngagePlatform(remoteMessage.data)) {
            try {
                val deeplink = remoteMessage.data[PUSH_NOTIFICATION_NAVIGATION_DEEPLINK]
                    ?: remoteMessage.data[PUSH_NOTIFICATION_NAVIGATION_DEEPLINK_LEGACY]
                if (deeplink != null) {
                    originalIntent.apply {
                        data = Uri.parse(deeplink)
                    }
                    intent = originalIntent
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Handle exception
            }
        }
    }
    super.onCreate(null)
}

// AppDelegate.mm
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Other initializations

    NSMutableDictionary *newLaunchOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:launchOptions];
    NSDictionary *userInfo = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (userInfo && !launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]) {
        if ([[MoEngageSDKMessaging sharedInstance] isPushFromMoEngageWithPayload:userInfo]) {
            NSString *initialURL = userInfo[@"app_extra"][@"moe_deeplink"];
            if (initialURL) {
                newLaunchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] = [NSURL URLWithString:initialURL];
            }
        }
    }

    BOOL result = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:newLaunchOptions];
    UIView *rootView = self.window.rootViewController.view;
    [RNSLoadingView setupWithRootView:rootView];
    return result;
}

And then on JS side the link becomes available using Linking.getInitialURL()
While this workaround solves the issue, I'm wondering if there are better ways to handle it? Thank you!

In iOS, when you have a custom scheme URL, the application(_:open:options:) method will be called with the provided deep link callback.
On the other hand, when you have a universal link, the application(_:continue:restorationHandler:) method will be called with the provided deep link callback.
For more information and examples on how to handle custom notifications using these methods, you can refer to the "NotificationActions" section of MoEngage's documentation: Custom Notification Handling.
If you're still experiencing issues or need further assistance, you can reach out for support by following the instructions in this document:Raise a Support Ticket Through MoEngage Dashboard.

This answer does not clearly explain why getInitialURL does not return the expected URL on iOS. Neither does not explain push notification behaviour specific to when an application is killed. Granted, the question could explain  better what about push notifications does not work when the app is killed.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
